# Asynchronous (non-blocking) display of alert in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, asynchronous

In my iPad App, am connecting to a web service. Whilst connecting to it, am displaying the progress activity indicator and a corresponding message to the user in a label (the label is in a subview and am adding the subview to the current view).

After this line of code (which calls a method to add the subview to the view), am invoking the method to call the web service. However, the web service call is getting executed first, and then only the user-information subview is displayed.

Is there any way to say that I want to 'continue displaying' the alert view even while the execution continues to the next line of code?

```
// Calling method to add info/alert subview to current view [self displayUserMessage]; 
// Connect to Web Service [self connectToWebService];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question. Also it's far more easy to understand if you provide some code after your explanation... Anyway what I understand is that you are connecting to a web service and showing some info while the connection is on going?

Remember that if you don't want to hang your user interface you need to send the webService Connection in another thread, so you can keep the main thread free. You can do so using GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [self connectWithWebService];
});
```

Then depending on the architecture of the web service, you can use a delegate o maybe a completion block to show some messages (info/alert) to the user. In that case remember that anything related to UI should run on the main thread. So as I said before depending on your architecture you should do something like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Show UI Changes
});
```

The UI should update properly while the webService method is running on background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want asynchronous connections its easier to go with `NSURLConnection`'s `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`..

you can display your alert before calling it and dismiss it in the completion handler.